# Where do I get Wordpress add_filter variables

Tags: wordpress

I am learning wordpress action and filter, action is easier to understand. but filter is hard.
Here is my question:
Below is the sample code, I got it from another site, it replace "best" to "second-best". What I don't understand is where do I get those variables in add_filter and cut_the_boasting?
What if I want to change the word 'Archive' to 'ABC' in default wordpress. What word do I use to replace jacks_boast and $boast?

```
add_filter( 'jacks_boast' , 'cut_the_boasting');
function cut_the_boasting($boast) {
 $boast = str_replace ( "best" , "second-best" , $boast );
 return $boast;
 }
```

This must be newb question, but many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only use a filter if that filter hook exists, and is applied to a variable with [`apply_filters()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/apply_filters). For your example to work, somewhere in the source code you would find something like:

```
echo apply_filters( 'jacks_boast', 'best' );
```

which echoes 'best', unless that value is filtered. With your filter applied, it would echo 'second-best'.